# Can we setup a SAML SSO request flow through multiple Applications from IDP

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

I am setting up a new SAML SSO. I will be receiving the request from Client to my Application 1. My requirement is that the same SAML request should flow till Application 2 through Application 1. I was only able to find the SAML request from Client to Application 1 and Client to Application 2 over the internet.  But the Flow must be like Client -> App1 -> App2. Please advise whether this setup is possible ?

Comment: By client and application do you mean identity provider and service provider respectively? Is the SAML request actually the SAML response containing the SAML assertion? If you're asking whether the same SAML response received from the identity provider by the first service provider can then be forwarded to the second service provider, this is possible but not supported by the SAML specification and not something I would recommend. The identity provider should send separate SAML responses to each of the service providers.

Comment: Yes.I mean the client as Identity Provider and my Application1 as service provider.Yes the SAML request is the SAML response containing the SAML assertion.Yes i was asking  whether the same SAML response received from the identity provider by the first service provider can then be forwarded to the second service provider. Please advise me on  1. when it is possible,how can i do it? 2.Why it is not recommended.The reason i am asking is.the users can Access the Application2 only through Application 1 and the client requires the user credentials to get recorded in the logs of Application 2.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the 'App2' is a SAMLv2 compliant Service Provider, then this can not be done as it has to check the 'audience' of the SAML Assertion and this is set to the first SP.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to make the App1 both the Service Provider and the Identity Provider but - a **Relay** Identity Provider. A R-IdP acts as a regular IdP to any app that uses it for authentication but in the same time it delegates the authentication to an actual provider.

Then, configure your App2 to use the App1 as its Identity Provider.

This way, you'll make sure that no illegal flow involving direct access to the App2 and no illegal message flow between the App2 and the actual Identity Provider.

Also, you won't try to abuse the protocol by reusing the very same token from App1 to App2 which, although technically possible, sounds like something that could sooner or later cause trouble.